# DynamoDB putItem and updating a single field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've got a table like

```
request
avgResponseTime
```

Every request that is done is logged to this table. I use `putItem` for inserting or updating items - but I like the `avgResponseTime` to be a "continuous value" (the avgResponseTime so far + the response time of the newly added request).

Is there a way to do that in a single operation?

Comment: How do you calculate the average response time without storing the number of requests?

Comment: The amount of requests is also stored in the db, forgot to mention that.

Comment: That value would have to be updated then too, right?

Comment: Yep, avgResponseTime and requests requires an update.

Comment: You can use an Update Expression for that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html

Comment: I’ll see if I can build a working example later today and write an answer.

Comment: But that would require me to have an already existing item - what if the item doesn't exist?

Comment: A good friend of mine once said: If the solution is more complicated than the problem you’re trying to solve, you’re probably doing something wrong. Wouldn’t it be simpler to just retrieve the entry from DynamoDB and, if it doesn’t exist write a new one, if it already exists, do the calculation and write back the result? Is this an academic exercise or a real problem you’re trying to solve?